# Django ValueError: Can't do subqueries with queries on different DBs

Tags: django

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'NAME': 'default_db',
'USER': 'user',
    'PASSWORD': '123123123',
    'HOST': 'localhost',
'PORT': '',
},
'omskgkh': {
    'NAME': 'general',
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
    'USER': 'user',
    'PASSWORD': '123123123',
    'HOST': '123.123.123.123',
    'PORT': '',
}}
```

## in my view:

```
def districtreport(request):

info = models.InfoAddress.objects.using('general')
kao = info.filter(okrug='КАО').values('home')

kao_accounts = models.Operation.objects.using('general').filter(account_id__home_id=kao)
```

On dev server with (default database is sqlite3) that view works fine, but on production server Django raise

**Exception Value: Can't do subqueries with queries on different DBs.**

Please, help.

**ADD**: 
models.py

```
class Home(models.Model):
  id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
  ...

  class Meta:
      db_table = "home"
      managed = False


class InfoAddress(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    home = models.ForeignKey(Home)
    okrug = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    ...

class Meta:
    db_table = "infoaddress"
    managed = False


class Account(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    home = models.ForeignKey(Home)
    ...

class Meta:
    db_table = "account"
    managed = False


class Operation(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account)
    ...

class Meta:
    db_table = "account_op"
    managed = False
```

Comment: can you include your `models.py`?

Comment: It is a hard and fast rule with QuerySet objects. If you're filtering a queryset by the results of another queryset, you'll need to explicitly use one of your databases for both querysets. I wasn't able to find a dynamic way around it

Comment: i'm using 1 database for both operations.  (   using('general')  )

Comment: Can't reproduce with latest cacheops. Try updating it. If this doesn't help please post full stacktrace, also consider posting a bug report here - https://github.com/Suor/django-cacheops/issues

Comment: Are u tried with python 2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one way to solve problem:
Change QuerySet to list and filter with it.

Answer (score 0):

Updating to cacheops 2.4.1 or later will fix it.

A [corresponding issue](https://github.com/Suor/django-cacheops/issues/161) is now fixed.

Comment: Updating is the answer. There is no other reasonable way to solve this. This is not the why question it's how one. And this is the how answer.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was caused by 'cacheops' app. Fixed by author.